# Proper time, geodesic and external force

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

Deriving the geodesic equation

$$ (\nabla_u u)^\mu = 0 $$

one uses the variation of proper time $\tau[C]$ along $C$

$$ \delta \int_C d\tau = \int_C d\tau \, g_{\mu\nu} \, \delta x^\mu \, (\nabla_u u)^\nu \qquad (1) $$

with *arbitrary* *infinitesimal* variation $\delta x$, 4-velocity $u = \dot{x}$ along $C$ and parallel transport $\nabla_u$.

On the other hand we know that the geodesic equation with *finite* external force $f$ is modified as

$$ (\nabla_\tilde{u} \tilde{u})^\mu = f^\mu $$

where $\tilde{u}$ is the 4-velocity along $\tilde{C}$ which is *not* a geodesic due to non-vanishing $f$.

Fine.

Suppose we have explicit solutions $x$ and $\tilde{x}$ for

$$ (\nabla_u u)^\mu = 0 $$

$$ (\nabla_\tilde{u} \tilde{u})^\mu = f^\mu $$

Is there a way to define something like $\delta x$, to find an expression like

$$ \tau[\tilde{C}] - \tau[C] \sim \int_\tilde{C} d\tau \, g_{\mu\nu} \, \delta x^\mu \, f^\nu \qquad (2) $$

in order to calculate the deviation of the proper time?

In contrast to (1) the *general* expression in (2) is *neither* infinitesimal *nor* arbitrary but would have to be derived exactly from the known solutions $x$ and $\tilde{x}$.